# What is CC VCO?

Tags: vco

I have been asked to implement a PLL using a CC-VCO. But I am confused about what does that CC means, is this means cross-coupled voltage controlled ossilator?

Comment: Potentially a common-cathode Colpitts VCO as described [here](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/82537/High_Frequency_VCO_Design_and_Schematics__VA3IUL.pdf)

Comment: If you're asked to implement an abbreviation you don't understand, would that not lead to a short email to whoever asked you, asking to clarify? What if the person asking you simply uses CC differently than anonymous people on the internet do?

Comment: Common cathode, common-collector, constant current(unlikely) or cross coupled are possible interpretations. Asking shows more intelligence than guessing.